# How do I import from files in my project directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying refactor some code I did in a single file into some more managable pieces.
However, I cannot figure out how to do imports within my own files to save my life.

I want to use mytest in sandbox.py. What is the correct syntax to do that? I have attached photos of the directory structure.
I'm using Python 3.8.2

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `testdir` as package by creating `__init__.py` file in `testdir`

## How to import in`sandbox.py`

```py
from testdir import testfile

a = testfile.mytest(something)
```